# change SVG color by button | jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have this code , this code do  this things:

1- load SVG image  from server. Succeeded

2- select all similar path color from this SVG 
For Example : select all blue color in SVG or select all green color in SVG. Succeeded

> No , i want after select all similar blue color in SVG , to change all
>   these similar to "red" by click button .. How i can do that ????

see my code ..... please help I am spend many day on it .

[my code](http://www.stirox.com/R/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following code in button click handler:

```
$("#my-div svg:first path[fill='#9cca15']").each(function(index) {
   $(this).css('fill', 'red');
});
```

Comment: one more Q , if i have SVG and i do not know the color contain , how can I know ???

Comment: $("#my-div svg:first path[fill]") you can try with fill attribute